# Simple HTML login page using PHP not working

Tags: php, html

In my `index.php` page, I have the following code:

```
<?php session_start();
    
    if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){

        $logins = array('admin' => 'admin','123' => '123','456' => '456');
        
        $Username = isset($_POST['Username']) ? $_POST['Username'] : '';
        $Password = isset($_POST['Password']) ? $_POST['Password'] : '';
        
        if (isset($logins[$Username]) && $logins[$Username] == $Password){

            $_SESSION['UserData']['Username']=$logins[$Username];
            header("location:dashboard.php");
            exit;
    }
?>
```

In the same page, `<body>` has the following form:

```
        <form action="dashboard.php" autocomplete="off" method="POST">
            
            <br><br><h2 align="center">Login</h2><br>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Username" name="Username"><br><br>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="Password"><br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="submit">
            
        </form>
```

I have created a separate `dashboard.php` file with the following code:

```
<?php session_start(); /* Starts the session */

if(!isset($_SESSION['UserData']['Username'])){
    header("location:index.php");
    exit;
}
?>
```

I am trying to allow the user to proceed to `dashboard.php` only if they enter the correct credentials. However, whenever I press the 'submit' button, I am not redirected to `dashboard.php`; instead, `index.php` simply reloads.

Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: On your login page your form has `action="dashboard.php"`, so this will automatically try and submit to that page, which will then say you don't have the session variables set and redirect you back to the index page.

Comment: This seems to have quite a confusing layout. It would be better to do the authentication at the start of `dashboard.php` rather than as part of your `index.php`. Or, as above, just leave the `action` blank, that will submit to `index.php`, your PHP code will then check the login names for some hardcoded values and redirect if appropriate.

Comment: I have changed it to ```action=""``` but can't seem to solve the problem. What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Your `<input type="submit" value="submit">` needs a name attribute

Answer (score 0):

first of all try writing "Submit" in the same way (un-capitalize the 'S')

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
```

And make sure to name the submit button accordingly `<input ... name="submit" />`. 
Also, according to your logic, the `<form>` should redirect first to `index.php`, which will then check if the form was submitted and redirect to `dashboard.php`

**However**, be sure to write the redirection this way
`header("Location: index.php");` with a capital 'L' and a space between the dash and the target's first letter.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Here's some simple code that uses a database as opposed to set user names and passwords etc in order to achieve what you are after.

Login.php

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();
 
// Check if the user is already logged in, if yes then redirect him to welcome page
if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] === true){
    header("location: welcome.php");
    exit;
}
 
// Include config file
require_once "config.php";
 
// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$username = $password = "";
$username_err = $password_err = "";
 
// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
 
    // Check if username is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
        $username_err = "Please enter username.";
    } else{
        $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
    }
    
    // Check if password is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST["password"]))){
        $password_err = "Please enter your password.";
    } else{
        $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
    }
    
    // Validate credentials
    if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err)){
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE username = ?";
        
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);
            
            // Set parameters
            $param_username = $username;
            
            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Store result
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
                
                // Check if username exists, if yes then verify password
                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){                    
                    // Bind result variables
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $username, $hashed_password);
                    if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
                        if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){
                            // Password is correct, so start a new session
                            session_start();
                            
                            // Store data in session variables
                            $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                            $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
                            $_SESSION["username"] = $username;                            
                            
                            // Redirect user to welcome page
                            header("location: welcome.php");
                        } else{
                            // Display an error message if password is not valid
                            $password_err = "The password you entered was not valid.";
                        }
                    }
                } else{
                    // Display an error message if username doesn't exist
                    $username_err = "No account found with that username.";
                }
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }

            // Close statement
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        }
    }
    
    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
}
?>
 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        body{ font: 14px sans-serif; }
        .wrapper{ width: 350px; padding: 20px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <p>Please fill in your credentials to login.</p>
        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($username_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <label>Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $username_err; ?></span>
            </div>    
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control">
                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $password_err; ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login">
            </div>
            <p>Don't have an account? <a href="register.php">Sign up now</a>.</p>
        </form>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Then your welcome or dashboard page would be as follows:

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();
 
// Check if the user is logged in, if not then redirect him to login page
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
    header("location: login.php");
    exit;
}
?>
 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Welcome</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        body{ font: 14px sans-serif; text-align: center; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Hi, <b><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["username"]); ?></b>. Welcome to our site.</h1>
    </div>
    <p>
        <a href="reset-password.php" class="btn btn-warning">Reset Your Password</a>
        <a href="logout.php" class="btn btn-danger">Sign Out of Your Account</a>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

After someone has logged in etc and done what they need to do, you also need a way of logging them back out again.

logout.php

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();
 
// Unset all of the session variables
$_SESSION = array();
 
// Destroy the session.
session_destroy();
 
// Redirect to login page
header("location: login.php");
exit;
?>
```

I could take credit for the above code, but it is simply copied from the link https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-login-system.php.

Comment: Hi Bob, if my answers been helpful/useful, could you please upvote it. :)

Comment: Done, but as I'm new to Stack Overflow I'm not sure whether my upvote will be counted. Thanks so much anyways!